# Constraint layout as a parent, my Linear layout doesn't touch the bottom, why not?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

My XML pattern is:

Constraint

-Linear

-Linear

-TextView

-Linear [doesn't touch the background]

Three buttons inside linear layout:

[image: three buttons inside linear layout]

My XML code  [the end part]:

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear_controlBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_start_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="start"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="reset"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="Set"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This looks like a silly mistake, but I don't know where the mistake is.

Comment: show us your full layout

Comment: post full xml code please

Comment: You should please show us all the layout code, but it look like your `LinearLayout` has some `marginBottom` value

Answer (score 0):

Please remove bottom margins or margins on Constraint layout and linear layout. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use for margin like this, set the right, left and top side margin, don't set the bottom side, if you set the bottom side margin then remove and the check

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
```